# Is it possible to compare an array string to a normal string?

Tags: java, arrays, compare, user-input

I am trying to compare an array (of strings) to a regular string from an input. Is this possible? I have my test code and it's mostly just says

```
incomparable types java.lang.string and java.lang.string[]
```

This is my test code:

```
 String[] yes = new String[5];
yes[0] = "yes";
yes[1] = "yeah";
yes[2] = "sure";
yes[3] = "yupp";
yes[4] = "okay";
System.out.println("Input");
String input = scan.next();
if ((input).equalsIgnoreCase(yes)) {
  System.out.println("compared!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient solution will be to create a set of Strings and then call set.contains to see if the input string is present in the set. Sample code:

```
 HashSet<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
    //All string are already lower case so no need of toLowerCase() here
    stringSet.add("yes");
    stringSet.add("yeah");
    stringSet.add("sure");
    stringSet.add("yupp");
    stringSet.add("okay");
    System.out.println("Input");
    String input = scan.next();
    if (stringSet.contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
      System.out.println("compared!");
    }
```

Comment: You need to convert the input to lower case for this to work. Also it requires the strings in the set to be lowercase (which is the case here, but should be mentioned...).

Comment: Suggestions: `Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();` (code to interface) then: `Collections.addAll(stringSet, "yes", "yeah", "sure", "yupp", "okay");`.

Comment: @fabian String comparisons are case sensitive. I have added a test code for you. You can check this http://ideone.com/iJRNTN

Comment: @AbhishekGarg: I know String comparison is case sensitive, but since the OP wants to use `equalsIgnoreCase` you need a workaround to use `Set`. In this case simply converting every sting to lower case would work, since `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)` iff `s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())` (assumning no `null` objects involved)

Comment: oh ok my bad I missed the equalsIgnoreCase part. Made the edit thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which index in the array to check it against.

All five entries in the array are different, and Java doesn't know which one to check.

You may want to use a `for` loop to iterate through all the possibilities, and compare each entry to the input.

Comment: is there a simple way to check all of them together or would it be something along the lines of       if((input).equalsIgnoreCase(yes[0,1,2,3,4])) {

Comment: It's a three-liner.
`for (String possibility : yes)`
    `if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(possibility))`
        `System.out.println("Compared!");`

Answer (score 1):

I would use some form of iteration to step through the array one element at a time:

```
for (String compare : yes){
    if ((input).equalsIgnoreCase(compare)) {
    System.out.println("compared!");
}}
```

Or something along these lines after you read in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming values in `yes` are all lower-case

```
String[] yes = new String[]{"yes", "yeah", "sure", "yupp", "okay"};
System.out.println("Input");
String input = scan.next();
if (Arrays.asList(yes).contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
  System.out.println("compared!");
}
```

or with lambdas, ignoring case, as suggested by **fabian** in comments

```
String[] yes = new String[]{"yes", "yeah", "sure", "yupp", "okay"};
System.out.println("Input");
String input = scan.next();
if (Arrays.stream(yes).anyMatch(input::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
  System.out.println("compared!");
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(yes).anyMatch(input::equalsIgnoreCase)` wouldn't require the `yes` array to be all lowercase.